# Rust pcap results in reported dropped packets in Ubuntu

Tags: rust, pcap

I've got a program written in Rust that is leveraging the pcap library.

The program is being run on an ubuntu instance (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS).

Prior to running the program, if I run netstat-i, the interface reports no dropped packets.

Once my program runs, the operating system reports massive packet drops.  Ironically, the packet drop is almost a 1-1 ratio of packets read from the capture device.

Once my program stops, the dropped packets stop increasing in netstat.

I'm suspecting that something about the way I'm reading packets is causing the OS not to register that I've actually read and processed the packet.

I'm creating the capture device by:

```
 let cap = capture_inactive
        .buffer_size(5_000_000)
        .snaplen(500)
        .promisc(true)
        .open()?
        .setnonblock()?;
```

Reading the packets is done through a packet stream:

```
let stream = cap.stream(BoxCodec);

loop {
   tokio::select! {
       packet = stream.next() => {
           count += 1;
           ...
       }
   }
}
```

Looking at the pcap stats:

```
let stats = cap.stats().unwrap(); 
println!("Received: {} ({}), dropped: {}, if_dropped: {}", 
   count, stats.received, stats.dropped, stats.if_dropped);
```

reports that there are no dropped packets in my program and through the interface.  Looking at the packet sequence data (the packets I'm capturing have sequence numbers), I can validate that I'm not missing any packets.

Is there some trick to using pcap that would signal to the OS that I've actually used the packet?